# UIStoryboardSegue: view is not displayed during animation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue, unwind-segue

When my custom segue's animation is being performed, destination view appears black. After animation ends, view appears and looks good.

Here are the screenshots:

Animation scene:
[image]

View after segue/animation finished:
[image]

Here is the custom segue class:

```
class SegueToPreview: UIStoryboardSegue {

override func perform() {
    // Assign the source and destination views to local variables.
    var firstVCView = self.sourceViewController.view as UIView!
    var secondVCView = self.destinationViewController.view as UIView!

    // Get the screen width and height.
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

    // Specify the initial position of the destination view.
    secondVCView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, screenHeight, screenWidth, screenHeight)

    // Access the app's key window and insert the destination view above the current (source) one.
    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
    window?.insertSubview(secondVCView, aboveSubview: firstVCView)

    // Animate the transition.
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in

        firstVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(firstVCView.frame, -screenWidth, 0.0)
        secondVCView.frame = CGRectOffset(secondVCView.frame, -screenWidth, 0.0)

        }) { (Finished) -> Void in
            self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController as! UIViewController,
                animated: false,
                completion: nil)
    }

}
```

While unwind segue works just fine, showing both views.

I suppose that the view is not loaded while the animation is being performed, but have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: Perhaps you misplaced the UI codes in the viewDidAppear instead? technically it is loaded already because you called self.destinationViewController.view

Comment: Also, I think you should initialize the frame of the secondViewController's frame in the viewDidLoad of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial position for the destination vc's view is setup incorrectly (assuming that you want the view to move in from the right); you have it positioned below the screen, instead of to the right of the screen,

```
secondVCView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, screenHeight, screenWidth, screenHeight)
```

This should be,

```
secondVCView.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)
```